# Printing file names from a certain directory?

Tags: python-3.x, file, printing

i'm tryng to print the names of all the files in a directory with it looking something like this

```
#the file names
file1
file2
file3
ect
```

The file structure is like this

```
folder
  mainfile
  folder2
    otherfiles
```

`print([entry for entry in os.scandir('formulas') if entry.is_file()])` ive tried this but it prints extra stuff and it doesnt skip a line per file

I want to print the names of 'otherfiles' using code from 'mainfile'
Sorry if this is weirdly formatted, im new to this.
I'm also pretty new to python so sorry if this is a super easy fix

(solved)
thanks atru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) returns objects of class [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry). This is what you were iterating through in your code and what you were printing.

You can get only the file name by calling `.name` member of `os.DirEntry`,

```
import os

for entry in os.scandir('.'):
    if entry.is_file():
        print(entry.name)
    else:
        continue
```

I rearranged your code a little - list comprehensions are great, but for a task like this I would personally go with a loop. Now you loop through all the entries returned to you by `os.scandir()` and print only ones that are files. If an entry is not a file, the code moves on to the next object. The `else` part is not needed here, but will be if you plan to do something after the `if`. I was looking at the current directory (i.e. '.'), you should change it accordingly.

Finally, in your code you were constructing a list - and then you were printing that list as a whole without any additional formatting. That's why you weren't getting your file names on new lines. Here you simply print each name separately, with a newline added by Python.

This said, a more minimal version would be as follows:

```
import os

file_names = [entry.name for entry in os.scandir('.') if entry.is_file()]
print('\n'.join(file_names))
```

Here the list is printed as a string created using `join` with newline as a delimiter.